# Sharepoint 2013 Document Library rename "New Document"

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, document-library

I feel as though the answer is simple, but I can't seem to get it right.  My client wants to rename where it says "new document or drag files here" to "New Travel Request".

Does anyone know how to do this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A demo code for your reference:

```
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ms-list-addnew").html($(".ms-list-addnew").html().replace('or drag files here','')); 
    $(".ms-list-addnew>a>span").eq(1).text("New Travel Request");
}
);
```

Result is:
[image]

Comment: This solved my problem.  Thank you so much!